# Zipping file in Ruby using system()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip

I'm trying to zip file using `system()` method, exactly like this:

```
system("zip /directory/filename.xml > /directory/filename.xml.zip")
```

Original file exists, I'm 100% sure of it, yet `system()` method returns false. What mistake do you see here?

UPDATE:

So far I've tried

```
system("zip -r #{zip_output_file_path} #{file_path}")
```

but it gives me

```
zip warning: missing end signature--probably not a zip file (did you
    zip warning: remember to use binary mode when you transferred it?)
    zip warning: (if you are trying to read a damaged archive try -F)

zip error: Zip file structure invalid (zip_output_file_path)
```

Comment: I see wrong syntax for `zip`. Should be something like `zip /dir/zipfile.zip /dir/file`

Comment: Better would have if you have used IO.popen3 as it would have output correct error or issue.

Comment: What is `zip_output_file_path`? Here should be name of zip file with path to it, not just path

Answer (score 0):

According to the zip manual `-r` travel the directory structure recursively.

Either you need to point to a directory:

```
system("zip -r /directory/filename.xml.zip /directory/")
```

or directly to the file, but without the `-r` option:

```
system("zip /directory/filename.xml.zip /directory/filename.xml")
```